# How to import FieldValue.increment() from Firebase Firestore in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to use `FieldValue.increment()` to increment a value but I keep getting the following error.

> TypeError: firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.firestore.FieldValue.increment is not a function

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

// ...

const getIncrement = amount => firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(amount)

// ...
batch.update(db.collection(path).doc('--stats--'), {count: getIncrement(1),},);
```

I suspect the problem might be with my import statement:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
```

I'm using Reactjs and I did:

```
yarn upgrade firebase
```

This is my yarn.lock file

yarn.lock

> firebase@5.5.9:
>   version "5.5.9"
>   resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/firebase/-/firebase-5.5.9.tgz#1e20172d7c7dfafdc75a18378439e0493bc12753"
>   integrity sha512-IFABX9++5Bq7S00zYGdkdnqikq67cJuub26iyap4qNPnc05qXxx/5waomMIyEvfH74K7ywOaVWEy0E1BFNKk7g==
>   dependencies:
>   "@firebase/app" "0.3.5"
>   "@firebase/auth" "0.7.9"
>   "@firebase/database" "0.3.7"
>   "@firebase/firestore" "0.8.8"
>   "@firebase/functions" "0.3.3"
>   "@firebase/messaging" "0.3.7"
>   "@firebase/polyfill" "0.3.3"
>   "@firebase/storage" "0.2.4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

- https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_592_-_mar_28_2019
- https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/upgrade/

You need to upgrade firebase version to 5.9.2 or newer.

If you want to upgrade to latest version then you can do the following command.

```
yarn upgrade firebase --latest
```